# click on firstElementChild in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code

```
console.log(RefOfList.current.firstElementChild)
```

and I'm able to see the correct node printed. But how do I click it programmatically?

this didn't work:

```
RefOfList.current.firstElementChild.click()
```

I got an error message

```
Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

Comment: RefOfList.current.firstElementChild.click()?

Comment: @Rumeee Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in trying Selenium.

The following should work:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //you can use whichever driver though
JavascriptExecutor jsDriver= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsDriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('<id of element>').click();")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a TypeScript question. If you know what kind of element the children beforehand, you can verify the tag name of the firstChild then type assert it.

For example,

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const parent = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const onH2Click = () => {
    const firstChild = parent.current?.firstElementChild;

    if (firstChild?.tagName === "BUTTON") { 
      // if firstChild is not null and is a button
      (firstChild as HTMLButtonElement).click(); // Hey, this is a Button!
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={parent}>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Click Me</button>
      <h2 onClick={onH2Click}>{num}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the `children` of the current node.  That is an array of elements.  It's as easy as calling `click()` on the `0` index of the `children` array.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const elem = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    elem.current.children[0].click()
  })
  
  return (
    <div className="App" ref={elem}>
      <h1 onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}>I'm clickable</h1>
      <h2>I'm the second element</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```